# pythonpath only work in one terminal

Tags: pythonpath

https://scipher.wordpress.com/2010/05/10/setting-your-pythonpath-environment-variable-linuxunixosx/#comment-219

I did this tutorial to set up my pythonpath variable in my Linux computer, 
the odd thing is that  I can only import my modules from /home

I did cd /home and vi .bash_profile, did the changes pointing directly to my folder with my modules, such

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:"/share/my_modules"

PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/share/my_modules"

export PATH

export PYTHONPATH
```

and save the file.
from there I can do python and import my modules,
but if I go to any other directory and I try to import my modules,  it fail =(.
if I do 
    import sys
    sys.path
my folder /share/my_modules is not there =(  but do show in the terminal from /home.

do I need to set up a .bash_profile file in each folder? I am missing something?
thanks guys.

Comment: You should consider using virtual environments. See http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

reading this document, explains that are 2 ways to set it up, 
one is modifying the /etc/environment file.

or making an sh file under /etc/profile.d/*.sh
and putting the variables  like
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

that way every time a terminal is open will run that, export those variables and will work.